# Calling values from an array using an array or string - php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem writing a code in which I can arrive at the values, but using text or an array

Suppose this Array:

```
$array = [
    'name' => 'any Name',
    'settings' => [
            'app' => 'Spy',
            'location' => 'Earth',
            'locale' => 'en'
    ]
];
```

and i want to get `app` value

default code:

`echo $array['settings']['app'];`

But this method is not working because I cannot write the parentheses [] [] in my case

#### I want a method similar to this:

```
$handle = 'app, name';
echo $array[$handle] ;
```

#### or

```
$handle = ['settings']['app'];

echo $array[$handle];
```

I know that the code is wrong, but an example

I hope that the idea has arrived and that there is a solution.

Comment: This is not  possible. You could rather play with references.

Comment: @nice_dev Do you know any idea ?

Comment: Any reason why to not use standard approach? Basic PHP syntax? `echo $array['settings']['app']` is shorter than `$handle = ...'; echo $array[$handle]`...

Comment: @pavel i  have a function that fetches data by typing keynames like this  : get('settings|app') this getting $array['settings']['app'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be something like that?

```
<?php

$array = [
    'name' => 'any Name',
    'settings' => [
            'app' => 'Spy',
            'location' => 'Earth',
            'locale' => 'en'
    ]
];

$str = 'settings|app'; // this is string you have

foreach (explode('|', $str) as $key) {
    if (!isset($output)) {
        $output = $array[$key];
    } else {
        $output = $output[$key];    
    }
}

echo $output; // spy
```

Comment: @Hothaifajaber: it should works independently on nested level - string `xxx|yyy|zzz` for 3D array should return correct value. You can try it.